# Reconhecimento de imagens dentro de uma imagem maior

Tags: javascript, jquery, processamento-de-imagens, opencv

Gostaria de fazer uma parte da minha aplicação, em que o usuário faria upload de uma imagem cheia de desenhos dentro, ele então, selecionaria uma área da imagem e eu procuraria em toda a imagem uppada, pontos iniciais nos quais essa imagem selecionada se repete dentro da imagem maior. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Alguma biblioteca JS? As que achei fazem reconhecimento de face e não de objetos em geral...

Answer (score 3):

Não conheço nenhuma solução client-side (JS) que possa realizar, com um grau decente de precisão, este tipo de funcionalidade.

Você pode, entretanto, utilizar uma solução server-side.

Uma das possibilidades é [OpenCV](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV), uma biblioteca opensource (BSD) multiplataforma desenvolvida pela Intel que possui vários módulos interessantes para processamento de imagens. No seu caso específico, o módulo [cvMatchTemplate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) pode ser uma solução viável.

Este é um exemplo de detecção via `OpenCV::cvMatchTemplate`:

Original:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alvo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão normalizada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigada, vou dar uma olhada porque meu projeto é PHP :(

Comment: @user3326192 Sugiro então dar uma olhada neste link - é um wrapper da biblioteca OpenCV para PHP: http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/

Comment: Eu consegui fazer usando métodos da gd2 (lib php) e transformando as imagens em duas matrizes com valores inteiros (inicialmente peguei a imagem, tranformei em grayscale [também com métodos da gd2] para facilitar) e com laços fui verificando... Deu certo! Obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: @user3326192 Que bom que você conseguiu encontrar uma solução! Sinta-se à vontade para caso você tenha mais dúvidas.